# How to use joins inside includes in rails active record query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am just trying to improve query, so that it result's in improving performance fo application.

```
 Student.includes(:parents =>:emails).where("emails.email_address is not null and emails.email_address != ''")
```

I just wanted to meet conditions using emails table, so clearly it is not required to eagerload emails table, instead i would prefer joins. But I am not able to figure out, how to use includes and joins together?. So that it should eagerload parents and joins with emails

Comment: what do you mean by not required, you mean the `emails` table can be null?

Comment: Have you tried `Student.joins(:parents =>:emails)` ? how did the results differ from what you expect? Have you read: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Comment: Then how to eagerload parents record, joins would result in n+1 queries for parents?

Comment: @Lymuel I just wanted to match condition of emails table, and for doing it why we should eagerload all the records in emails tables?

Comment: Eagerload will reduce the execute time if the table is too big , I don't know why would you  want to use joins instead includes.

Comment: @RubenBarbosa I know what eagerloading does, but why would i eagerload emails table if i don't want to display any information in views related to emails table. I only want to display information of parents table so I am eagerloading parents. But it is not wise to eagerload tables in which you just need to filter data.

Comment: Ohhhh, ok i didn't understand it at first. You are loading Student , Email (from parents) and parents right? I'll try to find a better behaviour.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you do this by chaining both together:

`Student.joins(parents: :emails).includes(:parents).where("emails.email_address is not null and emails.email_address != ''")`

The way it works is that `joins` will create a `JOIN` but not kep any of the data in memory, whereas `includes` will preload the data in memory but not create the join.

I suggest reading this blog post: https://web.archive.org/web/20200804112405/http://tomdallimore.com/blog/includes-vs-joins-in-rails-when-and-where/