# How can I show nested json form result where the nested one is from another model/table in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

why Rails does not show the joined table when I use the join method?
this is my code on my controller:

```rb
 def index
   @users = User.joins(:name).all
   render json: @users
 end
```

the nested name table doesn't show on users table, even if `name` have foreign_key `user_id`
this is the name result

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "miss",
  "user_id": 1,
  "created_at": "2022-04-15T15:02:28.948Z",
  "updated_at": "2022-04-15T15:02:28.948Z",
  "first": "mya",
  "last": "richard"
}
```

this is my name class model

```rb
class Name < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

this is the user class model

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_one :name, dependent: :nullify.
  ...
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :name
end
```

and this is the SQL code generated when I run the code

```sql
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "names" ON "names"."user_id" = "users"."id"
```

I really don't Understand why it doesn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use joins inside includes in rails active record query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37650493/how-to-use-joins-inside-includes-in-rails-active-record-query)

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong expectations. `joins` and `left_joins` do not select the columns off the joined table. The just add a `JOIN` clause to the database query.

This is commonly used to filter the results based on a the join table:

```
User.joins(:pets)  # all users with a pet
User.joins(:pets)  # all users with a least one cat
    .where(pets: { type: 'Cat'})
```

If you want to get columns from the joined table you need to select them:

```
User.joins(:name)
    .select('users.*', 'names.name AS name')
```

In some cases the database will only let you select aggregates though as it potentially ambigeous.

```
User.joins(:pets)
    .group(:id)
    .select('users.*', 'COUNT(pets.id) AS pet_count')
```

`preload`, `include` and `eager_load` can be used instead to load records and their assocations together:

```
@users = User.includes(:name)
@users.each do |u|
  puts u.name
end
```

Comment: I still don't understand why you're putting name on a separate table though.

Comment: This still not working it says ```column users.name does not exist``` same if I change name for names. And the last one return weird results....I'm new to rails and I train with randomuser API, name is in another model but it is inside user

Comment: This isn't meant to "work" as you haven't actually specified what it is that you actually expected to happen. This is a lesson in the fundamentals.

Comment: I don't really understand what's wrong here, can you send me link to the doc with this plz?

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Comment: Thank you man, I thought that was the simple part